# Stub code for SF to MC Integration to create and populate Data Extensions

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, integration, webservices, dataextensions

I am currently looking to build a VF/Lightning page in SF, where Users can dump in Subscriber IDs, and I will use integration to create a DE in MC, and dump this data into that DE.

I have downloaded the WSDL from exact target and created the required classes that are needed for the build.

Can someone direct me towards a stub or repository where the steps to get this done are present, so that I know what is the correct way to said objective.

Many thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: Any reason for not using the standard Marketing Cloud Connector?

Comment: I am not aware how to use MC Connector to move data from _Sent and _Job into SF Objects? Can you direct me to the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, then your question isn't clear: 
I am currently looking to build a VF/Lightning page in SF, where Users can dump in Subscriber IDs, and I will use integration to create a DE in MC, and dump this data into that DE.
This sounds like you want to populate data in MC DE

Comment: oops, yes, sorry, I confused it with another issue I am working on.  We allow our users only to send emails via Email Studio. The MC tab via MC Connect is not available to the users, hence the need to move the subscriber keys from SF to MC.

Comment: I don’t quite understand your use case. Don’t you just need to synchronise your subscriptions from SC to MC? Usually subscribers are just leads or contacts from SC which then ca be queried once they arrive in Synchronised Data Extensions in MC, and upserted to a spendable DE, which you can use an email audience in Email Studio